# MashupValueException when creating a Web Table Linked Service on ADF?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm experiencing a MashupValueException while creating a Web Table Linked Service and I wonder if someone here have come across the same issue.

[image: A print of the error message can be found in this pic]

The config of the Linked Service is as follows:

```
{
    "name": "WikipediaLS",
    "properties": {
        "annotations": [],
        "type": "Web",
        "typeProperties": {
            "url": "https://www.the-numbers.com/",
            "authenticationType": "Anonymous"
        },
        "connectVia": {
            "referenceName": "MySelfHostedIR",
            "type": "IntegrationRuntimeReference"
        }
    }
}
```

The error happens after filling the info on the form and clicking on "Test Connection". Then the following error pops up:

```
Connection failed
'Type=Microsoft.Data.Mashup.MashupValueException,Message=The supplied URL must be a valid 'http:' or 'https:' URL.,Source=Microsoft.Data.Mashup.ProviderCommon,' Activity ID: c8d924b9-cc81-49c1-85c8-70abfa85c859.
```

I have tested the extraction of the web table using Office 2016 and it works all right.

The aim is to extract the index 0 table from "https://www.the-numbers.com/movie/budgets/all".

Comment: I think these is something wrong with the web site. It doesn't look very stable.

Comment: Hi, any update on this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you are facing:

[image]

You can try to use below url, it can connect to the web successfully on my side:

```
https://www.the-numbers.com/movie/budgets/all
```

[image]

The website you give seems not stable. Sometimes you cannot visit the database.

Comment: I've just tried the way you suggested, @bowman-zhu, but no success. It helped me though. I will update the question later with new things I tried.